# Rails 3 library using Solr as the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I want to use Solr not merely as the indexer but as the database itself. Does anyone know of an existing Rails 3 gem? Essentially Solr would take the place of Sqlite or MySQL. I like to insert content and then later perform a search to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr is for indexing text and is not designed to be used as a relational database. I would recommend keeping a relational database and then submit that content to Solr for indexing, this would allow you to insert content and use Solr to search for that content.

Comment: I agree with Devin, but also want to add that solr-ruby is a good gem for interacting with solr. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/solr-ruby

Comment: I agree that solr-ruby is a good library however Sunspot has some cool features that may be useful inside a Rails application. https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot. I am a little worried that solr-ruby had its most recent on October 12, 2009 though.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at both of these gems. However, I am looking at the possibility of using Solr as the NoSQL db and as the indexer. Any ideas on a DSL/library.

Comment: You cant, Solr is not a database and not supposed to be used like that. What would you gain by using it as a database?